# How to add user defined attribute to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm adding ":foo" attribute to my user model as:

```
attr_accessor :foo
attr_accessible :foo
```

But when I set this attribute from a session controller or any other controller as:

```
User.foo = "my attributre"
```

and I get this attribute as:

```
User.foo
```

so these are not recognize and gives me an error, which is:

```
undefined method `foo=' for #<Class:0xb75366fc>
```

So please help here. **I AM USING RAILS 2.3.5**

Comment: You shouldn't use attr_accessible unless you want that field to be the *only* field that is accessible.

Comment: @ryan.. what do you mean by "the only field"..?

Comment: attr_accessible defines fields which are mass-assignable. If you used `attr_accessible :foo` then you could only assign `foo` during mass-assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_accessor` does not create a class method, it creates instance methods. So given your code, it should work to use:

```
@user = User.new
@user.foo = "bar"
```

### Edit:

However, if you do want to create custom methods, then you could do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.add_accessor(attr)
    define_method(attr) do  
      instance_variable_get("@#{attr}")
    end        

    define_method("#{attr}=") do |val| 
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}",val)
    end
  end
```

And then you call it from your Controller:

```
User.add_accessor "foo"
@user = User.new
@user.foo = "bar"
```

Comment: i did it as you told... but i am still getting an error... "undefined method `add_accessor' for #<Class:0xb75366fc>" :(

Comment: Sorry, missed that it should be def self.add_accessor. I'll edit

Comment: .. but i don't want to create the instance "@user=User.new"... i want to access "foo" directly - "User.foo"...

Comment: Okay, sorry for misunderstanding.. But then perhaps @Raghu's answer is more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want to have an attribute accesor at the class level
In the User model , Use this code

```
 class << self
      attr_accessor :foo
    end
```

Further reference http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor